# How do I do this in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, unicode-escapes

This is vb6 code

```
Dim i As Long, mystr As String

For i = 0 To 9

    mystr = mystr & "\u000" & i & vbCrLf

Next

Me.Text1.Text = mystr
```

The output has to be:

\u0000

\u0001

\u0002

\u0003

\u0004

\u0005

\u0006

\u0007

\u0008

\u0009

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mystr = ''
for i in range(10):
   mystr = mystr + '\\u000' + str(i) + '\n'

print(mystr)
```

Comment: Now, if I just put python mystr to the console without print I get ''\\u0000\n\\u0001\n\\u0002\n\\u0003\n\\u0004\n\\u0005\n\\u0006\n\\u0007\n\\u0008\n\\u0009\n'".    Print has changed the mystr string. The vb6 didn't have a print instruction. I would like the mystr to be "'\u0000\n\u0001\n\u0002\n\u0003\n\u0004\n\u0005\n\u0006\n\u0007\n\u0008\n\u0009\n'"

Comment: hi..are you trying to export the string to be read by another program?

Comment: I think I am trying to get a string with a lot of unicode literals so I can iterate them and print the character that the unicode literal pertains to.

Comment: if you were to iterate through mystr from the answer, it will only have one '\'